# VS Web Essentials - Generate .css.map files

Tags: visual-studio, web-essentials

Is there a way to make VS Web Essentials generate .map files for minimized .css files?  It'll do it for less-generated .css files, but I haven't figured out how to do it for regular minified .css files.

Obviously, I could rename the .css files as .less and let Web Essentials regenerate them, but my actual issue is that I'm bundling the .css files.  The bundle-generated .css file doesn't have a .map file, and for some reason, one of my bundled .js scripts is trying to load the non-existent .css.map file.  When the browser can't find it, the rest of the script is omitted.